# Disable constraints storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have updated Xcode from version 7.3 to 7.3.1
All constraints in file storyboard is missing, disable. How do you fix it?
[This is my screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfuhn.png)

Comment: your new xcode in storyboard select and check you are set UnSelect Use Size Classes

Comment: Check is the correct size class is selected from the storyboard and the Use Size Class checkbox.

Comment: Thanks! i resolve it!

Comment: Should we ask you what issue you had?

Comment: This is because of the size classes. You have designed your viewController in diffrent Size class like (wCompact hAny ), now it is opened in (wAny, hAny).

Change your size class to that specific class and use.

If problem persists and you have to disable size classes

Answer (score 1):

The constants are assign to a particular size Maybe this will help:-

Select all the constants

[image]

go the attribute inspector

[image]

remove the check at size class check box and check the installed.

[image]